# How to calculate the distance between a restaurant and 10 drivers who are nearby to that restaurant restaurant using longitude and latitude?

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

I have two tables:

```
------                  ---------
places                  drivers 
------                  --------- 
longitude               longitude

latitude                latitude
```

What I want to do ?

I want to calculate the distance between place and drivers to find at least 10 drivers who are close to the place and send them notifications.

My problem?

my problem is that I don't know how to calculate the distance from the place longitude and latitude and find the 10 drivers longitude and latitude who are nearby.

My code :

```
$order = Order::find($id);

 $drivers = Driver::where('id','!=',$driver->id)->get();

 $place = Place::find('id',$order->place_id);

 $place_longitude = $place->longitude;
 $place_latitude = $place->latitude;

foreach ($drivers as $driver) {

       if ($driver->availability === 1 )
        {
           $driver_longitude = $driver->longitude;
            $driver_latitude = $driver->latitude;

             $uuid = $driver->uniqid;
             NotificationHelper::orderNotificationForDriver($order->id,$uuid);
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$drivers = Driver::where('id','!=',$driver->id)->selectRaw ( "(6371 * acos( cos( radians('$place_latitude') ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians('$place_longitude') ) + sin( radians('$place_latitude') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance" )->orderBy('distance')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks bro.
Can you tell me what is this number: 6371 ?

Comment: You are welcome. Just use it, math is really depth :) 6371 is radius of earth

Comment: Is this help to you?